# Fastest way to search string?

Tags: java

what's the fastest way to check if specific letter/number appear in string (and how many times)? For example:

I let user write something and got "Test020301423" (ofc I store that data in string variable). Now I want to count how many times "0" appears in string. What's the fastest/best way to do that?

Comment: Iterate over the string and count matching chars?

Comment: Theres no way to know for sure how many occurances without looking at the whole string, so the fastest is just looking at every char

Comment: Just looking char by char into loop will do it in linear time. Are you looking for faster solution? I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to search for different characters in the string to check the availability and occurrences. If so, you can do the following:

1. Build a `Map<Character, Integer>` where you will store each character of the string as key and the occurrences as values. To build this map, you need to iterate through every character of the string. So it will take `O(n)` times to build the map.
2. Now for every search, you can just check if any specific character is in the map and if it exists then see the value (occurrences). It will take `O(1)` for every search.